# How do I swap two characters in a string variable?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string variable. I want to swap the two characters in the string word.
I want to randomly swap two characters which are close to each other.

This is what I have done:
I have done like this but in some words I get error.

```
string word = txtWord.Text;
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNumber= rand.Next(0, word.Length);
string swappedWord = SwapCharacters(lastWord, randomNumber, randomNumber + 1);

private string SwapCharacters(string value, int position1, int position2)
{
    char[] array = value.ToCharArray(); // Convert a string to a char array
    char temp = array[position1]; // Get temporary copy of character
    array[position1] = array[position2]; // Assign element
    array[position2] = temp; // Assign element
    return new string(array); // Return string
}
```

Comment: Try `rand.Next(0, word.Length - 1);`

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @L.B wasn't the higher bound **non**-inclusive?

Comment: @MarioStoilov see the next line `randomNumber + 1`

Comment: @L.B ah, yes. Didn't see that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the line as below:

```
int randomNumber= rand.Next(0, word.Length -1 );
```

Let's see if it works.

Comment: When I do this. I get it right but if the word is only 1 character I will get errors when I change the position of the word in the swapCharaters() method.

Comment: This is so because there is only one character in the string and in your method you are passing 'randomNumber+1' as well. Just put a check before it that says

Comment: if (randomNumber < word.Length -1) string swappedWord = SwapCharacters(lastWord, randomNumber, randomNumber + 1); else string swappedWord = SwapCharacters(lastWord, randomNumber, randomNumber);  I hope this will help.

Answer (score 3):

Use a StringBuilder:

//If you want to replace

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(theString);
    sb[index] = newChar;
    theString = sb.ToString();
```

//Swap

```
 string input = "AXBYCZ"; //Sample String
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    char[] characters = input.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
    {
      if (i % 2 == 0)
      {
        if((i+1) < characters.Length )
        {
          output.Append(characters[i + 1]);
        }
                   output.Append(characters[i]);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Also add checks if the word is empty.

```
int randomNumber= rand.Next(0, word.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It is easiest to change your code

```
int randomNumber= rand.Next(0, word.Length-2);
```